# Interpretation of a solution for a probability

Tags: probability

I calculated $P(X>1)$ for $Mx(t)=1/(1−t)$ by Markov's inequality,

$M'X(t)=1/(1-t)=1/(1-t)^2$

$E(x)=M'x(0)=1$

and according to Markov's inequality,
$P(X≥a)≤E(X)/a$

therefore,
$P(X>1)=P(X≥1)≤1$

My problem is interpreting the meaning of this result. To my understanding it means that there is no way of knowing the probability or estimating it.

Am I missing something in my solution or interpritation for it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Nope, it just means that the Markov inequality doesn't give a good bound in this case. To get something better, you would need to do something more subtle.

Comment: It was defined for me to use either Markov's inequality or Chishnev's inequality, but it didn't seem like Chishnev was getting me anywhere.Do you think it would be a better solution?

Comment: M(t) is a MGF, so there's no way to get a probability out of it.

Comment: are you sure? doesn't sound right..

Comment: definetly, the question is unsolvable.

Comment: sounds strange @jlammy do you agree?